# How to sign out all sessions after modifying role

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to invalidate the access token of a user after revoking some roles of that user.
I use KC introspection to validate the access token, but that API always returns roles at the time that the user logged in, but not the roles at the time I call the introspection API.
So I can't detect the changes in the user's roles.

I would like to ask, after revoking some roles of that users using Keycloak admin console, there is any mechanism to trigger signing out all active sessions of a user automatically?